# Using php to send mails with hMailServer and Ampps

Tags: php, email, ampps

How can I configure hMailserver to send out emails through a PHP script when using ampps on Windows 10.
I am running a website on localhost (ampps). I want automated emails to be sent out as soon as a particular condition occurs. I have installed hMailserver.

Comment: Sorry, but you will need to ask a more specific question than this.

Comment: It doesn't matter which mailerserver. Try [Swift](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) or PHPMailer to send emails.

Answer (score 1):

use a mailing librairy that you can install with composer instead of making your own
like swiftmailer for example
https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html